# Found a backup bash script, need to edit one variable to show date+time not just date

Tags: bash

In a backup script I found online for CentOs 6. It only saves the date in the file name and I need it to do time too.

```
d=$(date --iso)
```

How would I edit this to do date and time? I tried searching and reading tutorials for bash but didn't find what I needed or didn't know it would help me.

Comment: In what format do you want the date to appear?  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS or ...?

Comment: Oh forgot to write that. MM-DD-YY HH:MM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d=$(date "+%m-%d-%y %H:%M")
```

BTW, the date manual page (`man date`) contains all sorts of info on how date can display the date/time),